# Change between bash and zsh via terminal profiles

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, zsh

My default shell is bash, but I'd like to play around with zsh as well. I have a separate profile for zsh.

When I launch a terminal it opens a bash shell, and I'd like to switch to a zsh by doing something like "Terminal > Change Profile > ZSH". I've configured the "ZSH" profile to run the command "/usr/bin/zsh" as a custom command and tried checking "Run command as a login shell" as well. Neither seem to work - I'm still in bash.

Any tips? I know I can just type "zsh", but I have things configured in my  terminal profile I'd like to use as well, so changing shell and configuration in a single click is preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: If you go to File --> Open Terminal, you should be able to choose between alternate profiles there, no?

Comment: Thanks, @hightech for your detailed question. I got something useful from your question itself! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Per @steeldriver, "File --> Open Terminal" lets you open a new terminal with the specified profile, which works. Thanks!